# Compare two dates and set the fields value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this date field in angular

```
   <input bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="bsConfig" [bsValue]="maxDate" (bsValueChange)="setdob($event)" class="form-control bsdatepickerformat">
```

On Init event getting this value from api `this.user.dob`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.maxDate = new Date(this.user.dob);  
  this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate());
  this.user.dob=  this.datepipe.transform(this.maxDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

I want to check if `this.user.dob` date is `2000-01-01` then i don't want to show this date in field but it will be in this `this.user.dob` variable to be saved on updated. If user modifies the date field other than `2000-01-01` then new date will be updated and will be shown in date field.

Answer (score 0):

You can always  heck of the date is greater then equal to 2000-01-01.
Set a boolean variable to true or false or you can set the ID of your imput field and set the date on that.

So for example
Add id in your Input

```
<input #setDate bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="bsConfig" [bsValue]="maxDate" (bsValueChange)="setdob($event)" class="form-control bsdatepickerformat">
If(this.getDate()!= new Date("2000-01-01") { 

//set the input to user input value } else { 
//dont show 
}
```

Please let me know if you want a working example for that.